# What kind of tulip is this with pink flowers which resemble water lilies?

Tags: identification, flowers

I suppose the picture (taken today in zone 6, Central Europe) shows some kind of tulips. Am I correct and if so what (hybrid) kind could it be?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect they're Tulipa kaufmanniana - as to precisely which one, there are so many, I can't say. 'Heart's Ease' is a pretty common one, but the leaves on that are usually striated with brown, so I don't think it's that particular one.

Comment: Yup. Looks similar to [Heart's Delight](http://www.schoenesleben.ch/garten-balkon/pflanzen/bilder/fruehlingsboten-43/11) (link in German, sorry...). OP's photo appears a bit "too cool", colorwise.

Comment: This is just a guess, but might it be [Tulipa Fosteriana Concerto](http://lambley.com.au/garden-notes/muscari-wild-tulips-and-fritillaria)? The leaves look more similar in color and style than some of the other varieties. ([Close-up](http://lambley.com.au/sites/default/files/styles/full_image/public/garden_notes/tulipa_gesneriana.jpg))

Comment: @Sue Similar, yeah, but the flower color is wrong. Species tulips aren't very variable in flower color (per species).

Comment: @J.Musser  That's interesting. I always thought tulip species came in multiple colors! Thanks for the education!